# why http.response response inaktive?

Tags: flutter, dart

on my code repsonse.body or response.statuscode does not work. What is wrong here?

```
class Kategori {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  Kategori({
    this.id,
    this.name
});

Future<List<Categories>> getAllCategories() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.catshops.com/getAllCategories'));
  List<Categories> list = [];
  return getAllCategories();
}


try {
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
for (var map in map['categories']) {
list.add(Categories(id: map['id'], name: map['name']));
}
}
} catch (e, _) {
```

Btw try statement does not work, either

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Categories {
  int? id;
  String? name;

  Categories({this.id, this.name});
}
 Future<List<Categories>> getAllCategories() async {
    http.Response response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.catshops.com/getAllCategories'));
    List<Categories> list = [];
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var map in map['categories']) {
          list.add(Categories(id: map['id'], name: map['name']));
        }
      }
    } catch (e, _) {}

    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
class Category {
  int id;
  String name;

  Category({this.id, this.name});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}

Future<List<Category>> getAllCategory() async {
  http.Response response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.catshops.com/getAllCategories'));
  List<Category> list = [];
  try {
    if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
      list = (response.data as List)
          .map((item) => Category.fromJson(item))
          .toList();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }

  return list;
}
```

you can create you'r class (in dart struct) with this [website](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).